# How to upload file to backend in react

Tags: reactjs, file-upload

I'm trying to upload files to my backend program using react as front end. Back end is working completely fine in Postman. But when I try to upload it through react, it doesn't allow to upload. Same time I'm able to fetch the files from backend and display it for downloading. Below is my code for uploading:

```
const[selectedFiles,setSelectedFiles] = useState(undefined)
    const[file,setFile] = useState(undefined)
    const[progress,setProgress] = useState(0)
    const[message,setMessage] = useState("")
    const[fileInfos,setFileInfos] = useState([])

...

const uploadFile = async () => {
        setFile(selectedFiles[0])
        let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('file',file)
        await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/upload",formData)
        .then(response => {
            setMessage(response.data.message)
            return UploadFilesService.getFiles()
        })
        .catch(err => {
            setProgress(0)
            setMessage("Unable to upload the file at the moment")
            setFile(undefined)
        })

        setSelectedFiles(undefined) 

    }

...

<label className="btn btn-default">
          <input type="file" onChange={(e) => setSelectedFiles(e.target.files)} />
        </label>

        <button className="btn btn-success"
          disabled={!selectedFiles}
          onClick={uploadFile}
        >
          Upload
        </button>
```

When trying to upload, the following error message comes in console:

```
xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:8080/upload 400
dispatchXhrRequest  @   xhr.js:177
xhrAdapter  @   xhr.js:13
dispatchRequest @   dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise.then (async)        
request @   Axios.js:61
Axios.<computed>    @   Axios.js:87
wrap    @   bind.js:9
uploadFile  @   FileUpload.js:36
callCallback    @   react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @   react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch @   react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder    @   react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue    @   react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins    @   react-dom.development.js:8299
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1   @   react-dom.development.js:22396
batchedEventUpdates @   react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem   @   react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent  @   react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent   @   react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority    @   scheduler.development.js:646
runWithPriority$1   @   react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1   @   react-dom.development.js:22413
discreteUpdates @   react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent   @   react-dom.development.js:5889
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's check it

```
submit(){
    const data = new FormData() 
    data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile)
    console.warn(this.state.selectedFile);
    let url = "http://localhost:8000/upload.php";

    axios.post(url, data, { // receive two parameter endpoint url ,form data 
    })
    .then(res => { // then print response status
        console.warn(res);
    })

}
```

If your problem wont solve feel free to ask again.

RaminHbb

Comment: still it gives the same error and my backend is spring boot. it works fine with postmanapi